# Efficiently download and use images in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, image, download, android-recyclerview

Currently I'm using this to download and display the images in my recyclerview:

```
private class RetrieveImageTask extends AsyncTask<URL,Void,Drawable>{
    URL url;
    InputStream inputStream;
    protected Drawable doInBackground(URL... urls){
        url = urls[0];
        try {
            inputStream = (InputStream)url.getContent();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable drawable) {

    }
}
```

I then use this class in `onBindViewHolder` in my RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder item, int i) {
    try {
        item.title.setText(aushangdata.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
        item.desc.setText(aushangdata.getJSONObject(i).getString("text"));
        item.tag.setText(aushangdata.getJSONObject(i).getString("category"));
        item.link.setText(aushangdata.getJSONObject(i).getString("link"));
        URL myUrl = new URL(aushangdata.getJSONObject(i).getString("image"));
        RetrieveImageTask task = new RetrieveImageTask();
        Drawable drawable = task.execute(myUrl).get();
        item.thumb.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    } catch (JSONException | IOException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is obviously an extremely shitty solution, and it is very noticeable: when I open the fragment containing the recyclerview, I get a lag of up to 0.5 seconds, and when I scroll down fast it's also lagging because the images take up a lot of space on the cards.

My quesiton is: What is the most optimal way to download and display images in a `RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Glide: https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Also is so simple to use:

```
Glide.with(CONTEXT).load(URL or DRAWABLE).asBitmap().into(IMAGEVIEW);
```

Check the wiki for more options: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki

In your code:

```
Glide.with(context).load(myUrl).asBitmap().into(item.thumb);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issues with Picasso. The answer above me is right. Additional things you might consider: What i did to improve load time was use the methods `resize` and `centerCrop`.

```
resize(xxx,xxx).

centerCrop().
into(IMAGEVIEW);
```

Glide probably has similar methods.